# Return SCOPE_IDENTITY() and OUTPUT with Classic ASP in SQL Server 2012 - Error Obj Closed

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I am working with a Classic ASP (VB) application which needs to get the insert identity from a SQL Server 2012 table.

In development, I'm comparing `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `OUTPUT`, but the code:

1. returns more results than expected. The results are always 4 rows inserted into the table, with the last Identity returned in the application. Previously, I had tried the SQL without the 'Set NOCOUNT ON,' but received the error:

   > ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
   >   Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
2. an error message saying `Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'`.

How might the multi-row insert scenario be corrected, and what is the best approach to syntax with both of these, in VB?  Would the RecordSet need to be closed after insert, prior to select?

Thanks

First, the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_a]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col1] [int] NULL,
    [col2] [int] NULL,
    [col3] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Next, the Classic ASP (VB) code:

```
<%
'---- CursorTypeEnum Values ----
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Const adOpenDynamic = 2
Const adOpenStatic = 3

'---- LockTypeEnum Values ----
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Const adLockPessimistic = 2
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4


strSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON;INSERT INTO [table_a] ([col1],[col2],[col3]) VALUES (1,2,3) SELECT Scope_Identity() as ID;"


Set rsResults_a = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsResults_a.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic

if not rsResults_a.eof then
    Do until rsResults_a.EOF
    ResultID_a = rsResults_a("ID")
    response.write("<BR>"&ResultID_a&"<BR>")
    rsResults_a.MoveNext
    Loop
end if
rsResults_a.close
Set rsResults_a=nothing

'/////


strSQL = "INSERT INTO [table_a] ([col1],[col2],[col3]) VALUES (1,2,3) OUTPUT inserted.ID;"


Set rsResults_b = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsResults_b.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic


if not rsResults_b.eof then
    Do until rsResults_b.EOF
    ResultID_b = rsResults_b("ID")
    response.write("<BR>"&ResultID_b&"<BR>")
    rsResults_b.MoveNext
    Loop
end if
rsResults_b.close
Set rsResults_b =nothing

If objConnection.State = adStateOpen Then
    objConnection.Close
End If
%>
```

Comment: Neither of these approaches is very good, will post an answer when I'm near a computer.

Comment: You should be using stored procedures and parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `strSQL` needs a semicolon after `VALUES (1,2,3)`.

And the second one is invalid syntax and should be like the first (plus the missing semi-colon).

Comment: By "should be like the first," does that mean the addition of the missing semicolon, only, or something else, such as "set nocount on", in addition?  

I've made the semicolon edits, but still the multiple insert persists.

Comment: No, I missed that the purpose was to compare the first query to one using OUTPUT, so you should do the second query as described  by @JensBorrisholt.   I don't see any way your code could cause multiple inserts, so I suspect something else is happening that you are not aware of and are therefore not including in your question.

Comment: I've altered the first `strSQL` to be without `SET NOCOUNT ON`, and the multiple insert stops; however, I get the error described above.  Also, when I remove the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, the multiple insert stops, with the same error.

Comment: If you're doing everything exactly as you describe, then I have no explanation.  I know of no reason why `SET NOCOUNT ON;` would cause multiple inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a semicolon after VALUES (1,2,3) in your `strSQL`

```
strSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO [table_a] ([col1],[col2],[col3]) VALUES (1,2,3); SELECT Scope_Identity() as ID;"
```

if you realy realy want to achive the same result using the output keyworh then you need a SQL like this:

```
Declare @InsertOutput table
(
  ID int
);


INSERT INTO [table_a]  ([col1],[col2],[col3]) 
  OUTPUT INSERTED.ID into @InsertOutput
VALUES (1,2,3); 

select * from @InsertOutput;
```

Comment: In order to make a SQL string in VB, with the variable declaration you provided, would that all be done 'in line,' in one string?

Comment: Yes. It should be in one line